# Why isn't the year in my categorical array time properly converted in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, time-series

I have the following catergorical array in Matlab

```
time(1:3)

ans = 

  3×1 categorical array

     13-10-19 00:03 
     13-10-19 00:08 
     13-10-19 00:12
```

I want to use it as x-axis for a timeseries, in order to do so I need it as time string, so what I have done is the following

```
string(time(1:3))

ans = 

  3×1 string array

    "13-10-19 00:03"
    "13-10-19 00:08"
    "13-10-19 00:12"
```

If I cavert it using either `datetime` or `datestr` the year seems to be lost or wrongly converted

```
datetime(string(time(1:3)))

ans = 

  3×1 datetime array

   19-Oct-0013 00:03:00
   19-Oct-0013 00:08:00
   19-Oct-0013 00:12:00

datestr(string(time(1:3)))

ans =

  3×20 char array

    '19-Oct-0013 00:03:00'
    '19-Oct-0013 00:08:00'
    '19-Oct-0013 00:12:00'
```

Why is this? How can I convert the year properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to specify the [InputFormat](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#d117e275191):

```
datetime(string(time(1:3)),'InputFormat','dd-MM-yy HH:mm')
```

or

```
datetime(string(time(1:3)),'InputFormat','yy-MM-d HH:mm')
```

if it is 2013 in you example. It is not quite clear from the dates.